# Containers & memory leak

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, containers

```
void foo()
{
    std::list<std::string> list;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) 
    {
        std::string str ="text";
        list.push_back(str);
    }
    list.clear();
}
```

Why at the running func memory grow up, but after exec this func memory don't full free... 
For example: before exec func: 6'000 kb, at the running func: 200'000 kb, and after exec func it's: 9'000 kb... Any suggestions?

Comment: The amount of memory provided to your application is handled by the kernel. Your application can free memory all day, but all that does is tell the kernel that your application is done using it. The kernel doesn't have to remove it from your application.

Comment: I'm use Windows7, mingw 4.9.2 32b... And what can I do to free the memorry? In my project I'm allocate the memory more then in the example. And then I need to free the memory and allocate it again, but because of this problem the application crashed (memory overflow, but it doesn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial workaround may be to use a memory pool and custom allocators. The memory then is completely handled by your application.

The counterpart is that you have to implement it by yourself and handle it carefully (you can use [Boost.Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/introduction.html) for basic cases). Also, if your application is memory demanding in several points you shall share the pool, probably dealing with fragmentation problems.